# CSV containing JSON column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV log which contains a column which has JSON data. Screenshot below. I will also paste a sample of JSON data from one row.

Sample JSON

```
{"CreationTime":"2021-05-18T21:13:33","Id":"f12c6c27-8688-4074-edbf-08d91a41cb3b","Operation":"Set-Mailbox","OrganizationId":"0873ee4d-d342-44f2-8961-74c442a2fad2","RecordType":1,"ResultStatus":"True","UserKey":"NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM (Microsoft.Exchange.ServiceHost)","UserType":3,"Version":1,"Workload":"Exchange","ObjectId":"EURPR04A009.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM\/Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations\/dutchmasterz.onmicrosoft.com\/QuarantineOrgShard{368F7EFB-D8B2-448B-A304-41EA44801476}","UserId":"NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM (Microsoft.Exchange.ServiceHost)","AppId":"","ClientAppId":"","ExternalAccess":true,"OrganizationName":"dutchmasterz.onmicrosoft.com","OriginatingServer":"DB6PR04MB3206 (15.20.4129.032)","Parameters":[{"Name":"RecoverableItemsQuota","Value":"30 GB (32,212,254,720 bytes)"},{"Name":"Force","Value":"True"},{"Name":"Arbitration","Value":"True"},{"Name":"QuarantineMessageStore","Value":"True"},{"Name":"ProhibitSendQuota","Value":"99 GB (106,300,440,576 bytes)"},{"Name":"HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled","Value":"True"},{"Name":"SCLDeleteEnabled","Value":"False"},{"Name":"SCLQuarantineEnabled","Value":"False"},{"Name":"SCLRejectEnabled","Value":"False"},{"Name":"UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults","Value":"False"},{"Name":"RecoverableItemsWarningQuota","Value":"20 GB (21,474,836,480 bytes)"},{"Name":"IssueWarningQuota","Value":"90 GB (96,636,764,160 bytes)"},{"Name":"Identity","Value":"EURPR04A009.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM\/Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations\/dutchmasterz.onmicrosoft.com\/QuarantineOrgShard{368F7EFB-D8B2-448B-A304-41EA44801476}"},{"Name":"ProhibitSendReceiveQuota","Value":"100 GB (107,374,182,400 bytes)"},{"Name":"SCLJunkEnabled","Value":"False"}]}
```

[image: Sample log entry]

I want to extract what is inside the json and create a dataframe. So far I managed to use the following code. However, it sticks the columns names within each row than have a top header and then the values.

So in a nutshell I would like the data which resides in AuditData to be turned into a dataframe and have just a single header for it. How do I go about doing that?

```
dfo365raw = pd.read_csv('/opt/auditrecords.csv')
jsonout = dfo365raw['AuditData'].apply(json.dumps)
```

[image: jsondump]

SAMPLE raw csv records

```
AuditData,CreationDate,Identity,IsValid,ObjectState,Operations,PSComputerName,PSShowComputerName,RecordType,ResultCount,ResultIndex,RunspaceId,UserIds,"_bkt","_cd","_eventtype_color","_indextime","_raw","_si","_sourcetype","_time","date_hour","date_mday","date_minute","date_month","date_second","date_wday","date_year","date_zone",eventtype,host,index,linecount,meta,punct,source,sourcetype,"splunk_server","splunk_server_group",tag,"tag::eventtype",timeendpos,timestartpos
"{""CreationTime"":""2021-05-18T21:13:33"",""Id"":""f12c6c27-8688-4074-edbf-08d91a41cb3b"",""Operation"":""Set-Mailbox"",""OrganizationId"":""0873ee4d-d342-44f2-8961-74c442a2fad2"",""RecordType"":1,""ResultStatus"":""True"",""UserKey"":""NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM (Microsoft.Exchange.ServiceHost)"",""UserType"":3,""Version"":1,""Workload"":""Exchange"",""ObjectId"":""EURPR04A009.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM\/Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations\/dutchmasterz.onmicrosoft.com\/QuarantineOrgShard{368F7EFB-D8B2-448B-A304-41EA44801476}"",""UserId"":""NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM (Microsoft.Exchange.ServiceHost)"",""AppId"":"""",""ClientAppId"":"""",""ExternalAccess"":true,""OrganizationName"":""dutchmasterz.onmicrosoft.com"",""OriginatingServer"":""DB6PR04MB3206 (15.20.4129.032)"",""Parameters"":[{""Name"":""RecoverableItemsQuota"",""Value"":""30 GB (32,212,254,720 bytes)""},{""Name"":""Force"",""Value"":""True""},{""Name"":""Arbitration"",""Value"":""True""},{""Name"":""QuarantineMessageStore"",""Value"":""True""},{""Name"":""ProhibitSendQuota"",""Value"":""99 GB (106,300,440,576 bytes)""},{""Name"":""HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled"",""Value"":""True""},{""Name"":""SCLDeleteEnabled"",""Value"":""False""},{""Name"":""SCLQuarantineEnabled"",""Value"":""False""},{""Name"":""SCLRejectEnabled"",""Value"":""False""},{""Name"":""UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults"",""Value"":""False""},{""Name"":""RecoverableItemsWarningQuota"",""Value"":""20 GB (21,474,836,480 bytes)""},{""Name"":""IssueWarningQuota"",""Value"":""90 GB (96,636,764,160 bytes)""},{""Name"":""Identity"",""Value"":""EURPR04A009.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM\/Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations\/dutchmasterz.onmicrosoft.com\/QuarantineOrgShard{368F7EFB-D8B2-448B-A304-41EA44801476}""},{""Name"":""ProhibitSendReceiveQuota"",""Value"":""100 GB (107,374,182,400 bytes)""},{""Name"":""SCLJunkEnabled"",""Value"":""False""}]}","5/18/2021 9:13:33 PM","f12c6c27-8688-4074-edbf-08d91a41cb3b",True,Unchanged,"Set-Mailbox","outlook.office365.com",False,ExchangeAdmin,75,37,"2850e838-7c6a-4b61-a2e6-90e8c9b49bbb","NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM (Microsoft.Exchange.ServiceHost)","summit~1~C098987A-45B5-4F39-8698-92971DFA3F79","1:57652",,1626776388,"""outlook.office365.com"",""2850e838-7c6a-4b61-a2e6-90e8c9b49bbb"",""False"",""ExchangeAdmin"",""5/18/2021 9:13:33 PM"",""NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM (Microsoft.Exchange.ServiceHost)"",""Set-Mailbox"",""{""""CreationTime"""":""""2021-05-18T21:13:33"""",""""Id"""":""""f12c6c27-8688-4074-edbf-08d91a41cb3b"""",""""Operation"""":""""Set-Mailbox"""",""""OrganizationId"""":""""0873ee4d-d342-44f2-8961-74c442a2fad2"""",""""RecordType"""":1,""""ResultStatus"""":""""True"""",""""UserKey"""":""""NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM (Microsoft.Exchange.ServiceHost)"""",""""UserType"""":3,""""Version"""":1,""""Workload"""":""""Exchange"""",""""ObjectId"""":""""EURPR04A009.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM\/Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations\/dutchmasterz.onmicrosoft.com\/QuarantineOrgShard{368F7EFB-D8B2-448B-A304-41EA44801476}"""",""""UserId"""":""""NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM (Microsoft.Exchange.ServiceHost)"""",""""AppId"""":"""""""",""""ClientAppId"""":"""""""",""""ExternalAccess"""":true,""""OrganizationName"""":""""dutchmasterz.onmicrosoft.com"""",""""OriginatingServer"""":""""DB6PR04MB3206 (15.20.4129.032)"""",""""Parameters"""":[{""""Name"""":""""RecoverableItemsQuota"""",""""Value"""":""""30 GB (32,212,254,720 bytes)""""},{""""Name"""":""""Force"""",""""Value"""":""""True""""},{""""Name"""":""""Arbitration"""",""""Value"""":""""True""""},{""""Name"""":""""QuarantineMessageStore"""",""""Value"""":""""True""""},{""""Name"""":""""ProhibitSendQuota"""",""""Value"""":""""99 GB (106,300,440,576 bytes)""""},{""""Name"""":""""HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled"""",""""Value"""":""""True""""},{""""Name"""":""""SCLDeleteEnabled"""",""""Value"""":""""False""""},{""""Name"""":""""SCLQuarantineEnabled"""",""""Value"""":""""False""""},{""""Name"""":""""SCLRejectEnabled"""",""""Value"""":""""False""""},{""""Name"""":""""UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults"""",""""Value"""":""""False""""},{""""Name"""":""""RecoverableItemsWarningQuota"""",""""Value"""":""""20 GB (21,474,836,480 bytes)""""},{""""Name"""":""""IssueWarningQuota"""",""""Value"""":""""90 GB (96,636,764,160 bytes)""""},{""""Name"""":""""Identity"""",""""Value"""":""""EURPR04A009.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM\/Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations\/dutchmasterz.onmicrosoft.com\/QuarantineOrgShard{368F7EFB-D8B2-448B-A304-41EA44801476}""""},{""""Name"""":""""ProhibitSendReceiveQuota"""",""""Value"""":""""100 GB (107,374,182,400 bytes)""""},{""""Name"""":""""SCLJunkEnabled"""",""""Value"""":""""False""""}]}"",""37"",""75"",""f12c6c27-8688-4074-edbf-08d91a41cb3b"",""True"",""Unchanged""","DESKTOP-S7AJDFR
summit","UAL_csv",1621365213,21,18,13,may,33,tuesday,2021,local,,1337,summit,1,,""".."",""----"","""","""",""//_::_"",""_\_(..)"",""-"",""{"""""""":""""","AuditRecords.csv","UAL_csv","DESKTOP-S7AJDFR",,,,109,88
"{""CreationTime"":""2021-05-18T21:13:34"",""Id"":""1eaef902-e8e9-4153-a907-08d91a41cc22"",""Operation"":""Set-Mailbox"",""OrganizationId"":""0873ee4d-d342-44f2-8961-74c442a2fad2"",""RecordType"":1,""ResultStatus"":""True"",""UserKey"":""NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM (Microsoft.Exchange.ServiceHost)"",""UserType"":3,""Version"":1,""Workload"":""Exchange"",""ObjectId"":""EURPR04A009.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM\/Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations\/dutchmasterz.onmicrosoft.com\/TenantAllowBlocLists_F0767F09-6B4C-4F78-9234-2C0481176063"",""UserId"":""NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM (Microsoft.Exchange.ServiceHost)"",""AppId"":"""",""ClientAppId"":"""",""ExternalAccess"":true,""OrganizationName"":""dutchmasterz.onmicrosoft.com"",""OriginatingServer"":""DB6PR04MB3206 (15.20.4129.032)"",""Parameters"":[{""Name"":""RecoverableItemsQuota"",""Value"":""30 GB (32,212,254,720 bytes)""},{""Name"":""Force"",""Value"":""True""},{""Name"":""HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled"",""Value"":""True""},{""Name"":""Arbitration"",""Value"":""True""},{""Name"":""ProhibitSendQuota"",""Value"":""99 GB (106,300,440,576 bytes)""},{""Name"":""SCLRejectEnabled"",""Value"":""False""},{""Name"":""SCLDeleteEnabled"",""Value"":""False""},{""Name"":""SCLQuarantineEnabled"",""Value"":""False""},{""Name"":""UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults"",""Value"":""False""},{""Name"":""SCLJunkEnabled"",""Value"":""False""},{""Name"":""TenantAllowBlockLists"",""Value"":""True""},{""Name"":""RecoverableItemsWarningQuota"",""Value"":""20 GB (21,474,836,480 bytes)""},{""Name"":""IssueWarningQuota"",""Value"":""90 GB (96,636,764,160 bytes)""},{""Name"":""Identity"",""Value"":""EURPR04A009.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM\/Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations\/dutchmasterz.onmicrosoft.com\/TenantAllowBlocLists_F0767F09-6B4C-4F78-9234-2C0481176063""},{""Name"":""ProhibitSendReceiveQuota"",""Value"":""100 GB (107,374,182,400 bytes)""},{""Name"":""OrgPartition"",""Value"":""True""}]}","5/18/2021 9:13:34 PM","1eaef902-e8e9-4153-a907-08d91a41cc22",True,Unchanged,"Set-Mailbox","outlook.office365.com",False,ExchangeAdmin,75,36,"2850e838-7c6a-4b61-a2e6-90e8c9b49bbb","NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM (Microsoft.Exchange.ServiceHost)","summit~1~C098987A-45B5-4F39-8698-92971DFA3F79","1:57581",,1626776388,"""outlook.office365.com"",""2850e838-7c6a-4b61-a2e6-90e8c9b49bbb"",""False"",""ExchangeAdmin"",""5/18/2021 9:13:34 PM"",""NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM (Microsoft.Exchange.ServiceHost)"",""Set-Mailbox"",""{""""CreationTime"""":""""2021-05-18T21:13:34"""",""""Id"""":""""1eaef902-e8e9-4153-a907-08d91a41cc22"""",""""Operation"""":""""Set-Mailbox"""",""""OrganizationId"""":""""0873ee4d-d342-44f2-8961-74c442a2fad2"""",""""RecordType"""":1,""""ResultStatus"""":""""True"""",""""UserKey"""":""""NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM (Microsoft.Exchange.ServiceHost)"""",""""UserType"""":3,""""Version"""":1,""""Workload"""":""""Exchange"""",""""ObjectId"""":""""EURPR04A009.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM\/Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations\/dutchmasterz.onmicrosoft.com\/TenantAllowBlocLists_F0767F09-6B4C-4F78-9234-2C0481176063"""",""""UserId"""":""""NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM (Microsoft.Exchange.ServiceHost)"""",""""AppId"""":"""""""",""""ClientAppId"""":"""""""",""""ExternalAccess"""":true,""""OrganizationName"""":""""dutchmasterz.onmicrosoft.com"""",""""OriginatingServer"""":""""DB6PR04MB3206 (15.20.4129.032)"""",""""Parameters"""":[{""""Name"""":""""RecoverableItemsQuota"""",""""Value"""":""""30 GB (32,212,254,720 bytes)""""},{""""Name"""":""""Force"""",""""Value"""":""""True""""},{""""Name"""":""""HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled"""",""""Value"""":""""True""""},{""""Name"""":""""Arbitration"""",""""Value"""":""""True""""},{""""Name"""":""""ProhibitSendQuota"""",""""Value"""":""""99 GB (106,300,440,576 bytes)""""},{""""Name"""":""""SCLRejectEnabled"""",""""Value"""":""""False""""},{""""Name"""":""""SCLDeleteEnabled"""",""""Value"""":""""False""""},{""""Name"""":""""SCLQuarantineEnabled"""",""""Value"""":""""False""""},{""""Name"""":""""UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults"""",""""Value"""":""""False""""},{""""Name"""":""""SCLJunkEnabled"""",""""Value"""":""""False""""},{""""Name"""":""""TenantAllowBlockLists"""",""""Value"""":""""True""""},{""""Name"""":""""RecoverableItemsWarningQuota"""",""""Value"""":""""20 GB (21,474,836,480 bytes)""""},{""""Name"""":""""IssueWarningQuota"""",""""Value"""":""""90 GB (96,636,764,160 bytes)""""},{""""Name"""":""""Identity"""",""""Value"""":""""EURPR04A009.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM\/Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations\/dutchmasterz.onmicrosoft.com\/TenantAllowBlocLists_F0767F09-6B4C-4F78-9234-2C0481176063""""},{""""Name"""":""""ProhibitSendReceiveQuota"""",""""Value"""":""""100 GB (107,374,182,400 bytes)""""},{""""Name"""":""""OrgPartition"""",""""Value"""":""""True""""}]}"",""36"",""75"",""1eaef902-e8e9-4153-a907-08d91a41cc22"",""True"",""Unchanged""","DESKTOP-S7AJDFR
summit","UAL_csv",1621365214,21,18,13,may,34,tuesday,2021,local,,1337,summit,1,,""".."",""----"","""","""",""//_::_"",""_\_(..)"",""-"",""{"""""""":""""","AuditRecords.csv","UAL_csv","DESKTOP-S7AJDFR",,,,109,88
"{""CreationTime"":""2021-05-18T21:13:35"",""Id"":""b78265e8-5d20-4cdf-3e10-08d91a41cc86"",""Operation"":""Set-MailboxPlan"",""OrganizationId"":""0873ee4d-d342-44f2-8961-74c442a2fad2"",""RecordType"":1,""ResultStatus"":""True"",""UserKey"":""NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM (Microsoft.Exchange.ServiceHost)"",""UserType"":3,""Version"":1,""Workload"":""Exchange"",""ObjectId"":""EURPR04A009.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM\/Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations\/dutchmasterz.onmicrosoft.com\/ExchangeOnlineEssentials-eca5b2bb-bfe7-4c13-8820-0743c2c42bb6"",""UserId"":""NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM (Microsoft.Exchange.ServiceHost)"",""AppId"":"""",""ClientAppId"":"""",""ExternalAccess"":true,""OrganizationName"":""dutchmasterz.onmicrosoft.com"",""OriginatingServer"":""DB6PR04MB3206 (15.20.4129.032)"",""Parameters"":[{""Name"":""Identity"",""Value"":""EURPR04A009.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM\/Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations\/dutchmasterz.onmicrosoft.com\/ExchangeOnlineEssentials-eca5b2bb-bfe7-4c13-8820-0743c2c42bb6""},{""Name"":""UseDatabaseRetentionDefaults"",""Value"":""False""},{""Name"":""RecoverableItemsQuota"",""Value"":""30 GB (32,212,254,720 bytes)""},{""Name"":""RecoverableItemsWarningQuota"",""Value"":""20 GB (21,474,836,480 bytes)""}]}","5/18/2021 9:13:35 PM","b78265e8-5d20-4cdf-3e10-08d91a41cc86",True,Unchanged,"Set-MailboxPlan","outlook.office365.com",False,ExchangeAdmin,75,35,"2850e838-7c6a-4b61-a2e6-90e8c9b49bbb","NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM (Microsoft.Exchange.ServiceHost)","summit~1~C098987A-45B5-4F39-8698-92971DFA3F79","1:57531",,1626776388,"""outlook.office365.com"",""2850e838-7c6a-4b61-a2e6-90e8c9b49bbb"",""False"",""ExchangeAdmin"",""5/18/2021 9:13:35 PM"",""NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM (Microsoft.Exchange.ServiceHost)"",""Set-MailboxPlan"",""{""""CreationTime"""":""""2021-05-18T21:13:35"""",""""Id"""":""""b78265e8-5d20-4cdf-3e10-08d91a41cc86"""",""""Operation"""":""""Set-MailboxPlan"""",""""OrganizationId"""":""""0873ee4d-d342-44f2-8961-74c442a2fad2"""",""""RecordType"""":1,""""ResultStatus"""":""""True"""",""""UserKey"""":""""NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM (Microsoft.Exchange.ServiceHost)"""",""""UserType"""":3,""""Version"""":1,""""Workload"""":""""Exchange"""",""""ObjectId"""":""""EURPR04A009.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM\/Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations\/dutchmasterz.onmicrosoft.com\/ExchangeOnlineEssentials-eca5b2bb-bfe7-4c13-8820-0743c2c42bb6"""",""""UserId"""":""""NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM (Microsoft.Exchange.ServiceHost)"""",""""AppId"""":"""""""",""""ClientAppId"""":"""""""",""""ExternalAccess"""":true,""""OrganizationName"""":""""dutchmasterz.onmicrosoft.com"""",""""OriginatingServer"""":""""DB6PR04MB3206 (15.20.4129.032)"""",""""Parameters"""":[{""""Name"""":""""Identity"""",""""Value"""":""""EURPR04A009.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM\/Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations\/dutchmasterz.onmicrosoft.com\/ExchangeOnlineEssentials-eca5b2bb-bfe7-4c13-8820-0743c2c42bb6""""},{""""Name"""":""""UseDatabaseRetentionDefaults"""",""""Value"""":""""False""""},{""""Name"""":""""RecoverableItemsQuota"""",""""Value"""":""""30 GB (32,212,254,720 bytes)""""},{""""Name"""":""""RecoverableItemsWarningQuota"""",""""Value"""":""""20 GB (21,474,836,480 bytes)""""}]}"",""35"",""75"",""b78265e8-5d20-4cdf-3e10-08d91a41cc86"",""True"",""Unchanged""","DESKTOP-S7AJDFR
summit","UAL_csv",1621365215,21,18,13,may,35,tuesday,2021,local,,1337,summit,1,,""".."",""----"","""","""",""//_::_"",""_\_(..)"",""-"",""{"""""""":""""","AuditRecords.csv","UAL_csv","DESKTOP-S7AJDFR",,,,109,88
```

Comment: Can you make a small example program? You could have a CSV of a few rows and columns with small, boring JSON strings. Then we have something to work with.

Comment: Agree with @tdelaney's comment. Didn't even share the data for several rows... shared the screenshot. How to parse data from screenshot? :P

Comment: You want just that first column extracted as a dataframe? Perhaps `jsonout = pd.DataFrame(dfo365raw['AuditData'].apply(json.dumps))`?

Comment: if you have JSON as string then you need `json.loads` instead of `json.dumps` - to convert string to dictionary. And later you may need `apply(pd.Series)` to convert dictionary to separated columns.

Comment: @MilonSarker Added rows

Comment: @tdelaney results in <a href="https://ibb.co/xS9g7s0"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/d0Cp5cq/Window25.jpg" alt="Window25" border="0"></a> It has the columns per row. For e.g. CreationTime should be its down column  etc..

Answer (score 1):

can you try this:

```
df=df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop('AuditData'))).drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: Looks like it doesn't show the columns such as ClientIPAddress when I run that. I noticed that several other columns goes missing too.

Comment: Okey can you add current output ?

Comment: Sure I did a df.head(3) and pasted the output below
https://jpst.it/2_sC2